# "npm install" install non-used package

Tags: npm, npm-install

I am working on **nodejs-express** project, when I try to run "`npm install`" on another machine to install dependencies, npm install many modules that are not indexed in the package.json such as angular etc ..

what is the problem? does npm install also global modules?

Answer (score 1):

It would help if you posted your package.json.

But - I suspect what is happening is NPM is also installing the dependancies from your own project's dependancies.

Each dependancy in your project's node_modules folder will have it's own package.json, with it's own dependancies. NPM will recursively install all dependancies you asked for, as well as the packages that were asked for by your project.

This is expected behaviour - but can cause conflicts when two packages require different versions of the same dependancy. (i.e jQuery version 1.2 and jQuery version 1.5).